# pthread mutex: get state

Tags: pthreads, mutex, state

I was looking through some code that provides a C/C++ wrapper for a pthread mutex. The code keeps a shadow variable for signaled/not signaled condition. The code also ignores return values from functions like `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_trylock`, so the shadow variable may not accurately reflect the state of the mutex (ignoring the minor race condition).

Does pthread provide a way to query a mutex for its state? A quick read of the [pthread API](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread/) does not appear to offer one. I also don't see anything interesting that operates on `pthread_mutexattr_t`.

Or should one use `trylock`, rely upon `EBUSY`, and give up ownership if acquired?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function because there would be no point.  If you queried the state of a mutex without trying to acquire it, as `pthread_mutex_trylock()` does, then the result you get could be invalidated immediately by another thread changing that mutex's state.

Comment: OK, it sounds like a bad design from this library.